# INSERT JOIN WHERE issue

Tags: mysql, sql

The design of the database is:

Members to Membership_Link (1 to Many).

Membership_Link to Membership_Type (Many to 1).

I am trying to insert data into Members while linking it to an item in Membership_Type. I am hoping to do this in 1 SQL command and not break it out into 3 queries.

```
INSERT INTO members
SET members.username = "Test"
    ,members.email = "test@test.com"
    ,members.password = "Password"
LEFT JOIN membership_link ON members.id = membership_link.user_id
RIGHT JOIN membership_type ON membership_link.type_id = membership_type.id
WHERE membership_type.name = "Admin"
```

Comment: An SQL `insert` can only insert in one table at a time, so you will need 3 queries to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading your question i hopeyou required something like creating a member, so i dont know why you required member_link and member_type

So, for this you just have to write

```
 INSERT into members values (name, email, passowrd);
```

But after reading your query written, seems like you required to update the member having member_type = admin

So, for this you have to do two queries

```
 SELECT members.id from members LEFT JOIN `membership_link` ON members.id=membership_link.user_id RIGHT JOIN `membership_type` ON membership_link.type_id=membership_type.id WHERE membership_type.name = "Admin"
```

After having the result you will get the id. So, update your row based of members.id

```
  UPDATE members SET members.username = "Test", members.email = "test@test.com", members.password = "Password" WHERE members.id = {id}
```

**Updated Answer**

You can do this thing with 3 queries there is no possible way of doing this as you have to insert data in two different tables

So you can first insert the data in members table and keep the id of it
Then find the membership_type_id using selet query and then you can insert the value in the membership_link table

Comment: The SELECT members.id... this updated my first row, but it did not create new row, when I ran the Update it updated the first row only.

Comment: So, you want to update the same data in a row and also create a row

Comment: That is correct, I am making a login with user rights, and assigning a user right at account creation.

Comment: Okay so, please correct me if I am wrong.... You want something like creating a member and assign permissions to that created user

Comment: Yes. The Member_type holds types of permission's.

Comment: So, i think you can first insert the data in the row and then insert membership_link

Answer (score 1):

**Use Update in place of Insert Because you are updating your Table not inserting.**

```
Update members
LEFT JOIN `membership_link` ON members.id=membership_link.user_id
RIGHT JOIN `membership_type` ON membership_link.type_id=membership_type.id
SET members.username = "Test", 
members.email = "test@test.com", 
members.password = "Password"
WHERE membership_type.name = "Admin"
```

Comment: I have changed INSERT INTO to UPDATE. I am now getting SQL syntax error: 1064

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your mysql server version for the right syntax to use near 'LEFT JOIN `membership_link` ON membership.id=membership.user_id RIGHT JOIN `m' at line 2

Comment: It did not error out, but 0 rows affected. Also it did not insert the data to the database.

Comment: Why are you joining those table if you are not using them for update

Comment: Give me sample data and expected output then I can help you betterly

Comment: I am creating a login on a web page, when someone register's on the web page, I want to give them the lowest access, but if a admin register's someone, they can give what access they need.

Comment: add sample data and your expected output in question